Please help me to write a script that can buy on Jupiter through a squad wallet
import {
  Connection,
  ConnectionConfig,
  Keypair,
  PublicKey,
  TransactionMessage,
  VersionedMessage,
  VersionedTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import path from "path";
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
import * as multisig from "@sqds/multisig";

const { Permission, Permissions } = multisig.types;

const JUP_ENDPOINT = "https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6";
const RPC_URL = "api.mainnet-beta.solana";
const MULTISIG_ADDRESS = new PublicKey(
  "xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx"
);

const keyFileContents = JSON.parse(
  readFileSync(path.join("./keypair.json")).toString()
);

const creator = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(keyFileContents));

console.log("✨ creator:", creator.publicKey.toBase58());

const config: ConnectionConfig = {
  commitment: "confirmed",
  disableRetryOnRateLimit: false,
  confirmTransactionInitialTimeout: 60000,
};

const connection = new Connection(RPC_URL, config);

const [vaultPda] = multisig.getVaultPda({
  multisigPda: MULTISIG_ADDRESS,
  index: 0,
});

console.log("✨ vault pda:", vaultPda.toBase58());

const getQuote = async (
  fromMint: PublicKey,
  toMint: PublicKey,
  amount: number
) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${JUP_ENDPOINT}/quote?outputMint=${toMint.toBase58()}&inputMint=${fromMint.toBase58()}&amount=${amount}&slippage=0.5&onlyDirectRoutes=true`
    );
    return response.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Fetching swap transaction issue", err);
  }
};

const getSwapTransaction = async (user: PublicKey, quote: any) => {
  try {
    const data = {
      quoteResponse: quote,
      userPublicKey: user.toBase58(),
      prioritizationFeeLamports: "auto",
      wrapAndUnwrapSol: true,
    };

    const response = await fetch(`${JUP_ENDPOINT}/swap`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });

    return response.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Fetching swap transaction issue", err);
  }
};

const tokenSwap = async (swapTransaction: any) => {
  try {
    // deserialize the transaction
    const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(swapTransaction, "base64");
    const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);

    console.log("✨ transaction:", transaction);
    const transactionMessage: VersionedMessage = transaction.message;

    // Get the current multisig transaction index
    const multisigInfo = await multisig.accounts.Multisig.fromAccountAddress(
      connection,
      MULTISIG_ADDRESS
    );

    const currentTransactionIndex = Number(multisigInfo.transactionIndex);

    const newTransactionIndex = BigInt(currentTransactionIndex + 1);

    console.log("✨ newTransactionIndex:", newTransactionIndex);

    console.log("✨ Creating vault transaction...");
    const signature1 = await multisig.rpc.vaultTransactionCreate({
      connection,
      feePayer: creator,
      multisigPda: MULTISIG_ADDRESS,
      transactionIndex: newTransactionIndex,
      creator: creator.publicKey,
      vaultIndex: 0,
      ephemeralSigners: 0,
      transactionMessage: transactionMessage,
      memo: "token Swap on Jupiter",
    });

    await connection.confirmTransaction(signature1);
    console.log("✅ Transaction created:", signature1);

    // Todo: Proposal approve step

    // Todo: Transaction execution step
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Setup error", error);
  }
};

const main = async () => {
  const SOL = new PublicKey("So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112");
  const USDC = new PublicKey("EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v");

  // Find the best Quote from the Jupiter API
  const quote = await getQuote(SOL, USDC, 100000000);
  console.log({ quote });

  const programConfigPda = multisig.getProgramConfigPda({})[0];

  console.log("✨ Program Config PDA:", programConfigPda.toBase58());

  const programConfig =
    await multisig.accounts.ProgramConfig.fromAccountAddress(
      connection,
      programConfigPda
    );

  const configTreasury = programConfig.treasury;

  console.log("✨ configTreasury:", programConfigPda.toBase58());

  const result: any = await getSwapTransaction(vaultPda, quote);

  const { swapTransaction } = result;

  await tokenSwap(swapTransaction);
};

main().catch(console.error);

I am getting below issue in this part
const signature1 = await multisig.rpc.vaultTransactionCreate({
      connection,
      feePayer: creator,
      multisigPda: MULTISIG_ADDRESS,
      transactionIndex: newTransactionIndex,
      creator: creator.publicKey,
      vaultIndex: 0,
      ephemeralSigners: 0,
      transactionMessage: transactionMessage,
      memo: "token Swap on Jupiter",
    });

Type 'VersionedMessage' is not assignable to type 'TransactionMessage'.
  Type 'Message' is missing the following properties from type 'TransactionMessage': payerKey, compileToLegacyMessage, compileToV0Messagets(2322)
vaultTransactionCreate.d.ts(16, 5): The expected type comes from property 'transactionMessage' which is declared here on type '{ connection: Connection; feePayer: Signer; multisigPda: PublicKey; transactionIndex: bigint; creator: PublicKey; rentPayer?: PublicKey | undefined; ... 7 more ...; programId?: PublicKey | undefined; }'

I am getting VersionedTransaction is from jupiter swap API, but in Multisig vault transaction, it needs legacy TransactionMessage.
Thanks in advance

You'll need to get the instruction from the versioned message and then create a new TransactionMessage object with said instructions.
const ixs = TransactionMessage.decompile(tx.message).instructions;
const transactionMessage = new TransactionMessage({
    payerKey: creator,
    recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
    instructions: [...ixs],
});

